# Checking worksheet for value in array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet called Ch Data with a varying # of identically sized tables on it. Cells J5, J20, etc contain user-entered labels for each table. I want to compare these table labels to a named range of allowed table labels. If the user entered table label is not in the named range, a message should tell the user to enter a valid label. I have tried reading the named range into an array and then looping through the table labels and the array elements to compare them. I get an error on the line with the IF statement. The error is: "Object doesn't support this property or method". I suspect I have failed to define or reference the array correctly. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim LLChannels(), i As Long, j As Long
    Set ChData = Sheets("Ch Data")

    LLChannels = Application.Transpose(ChData.Range("Channels" & SymbolCount).Value)

    NumTables = (UsedRange.Rows.Count - 4) / 15
    For i = 5 To NumTables Step 15
        For j = 1 To UBound(LLChannels)
            If LLChannels(j) <> Me.Cells.["J" & i] Then
                MsgBox "Channel not in Frequency Plan. Enter valid channel."
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
If LLChannels(j) <> Range("J" & i).Value
```

Comment: That fixes the error, thanks. Unfortunately, the code still does not do what I intend, but your fix has gotten me closer.